# Ubuntu 20.10 crash on USB boot

Tags: crash, bootloader

I has created a USB boot from Ubuntu 20.10 image and on load it crashes.
The mouse's pointer has freeze and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't work.

I just changed the USB image but didn't work.
I came back to Ubuntu 20.04, it's fine.

I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: What is your end goal? Why couldn't you stay with 20.04?

Comment: My goal is install Ubuntu 20.10. why I need to stay with 20.04?

Comment: Then, when you have a working 20.04, why don't you just upgrade it with `update-manager` or `do-release-upgrade`? Necessary steps are for example here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-10

Comment: It was my first trying. After upgrade and reboot, It has freezing. Than I try out a full instalation from a USB drive but he Ubuntu freezing on first screen.

Comment: the cause of freeze is the keyboard/touchpad is not recognized by Ubuntu 20.10.I tried use bluetooth keyboard and mouse and works. But, how to solve this after installation?

Comment: Post another question 'keyboard/touchpad is not recognized by Ubuntu 20.10', with information about laptop make/model, also the output of `sudo dmesg | grep 'PS/2\|keyboard\ as'` from a running sytem. That might help to get answers.

Comment: command returns:
i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP030b:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4

Comment: notebook ASUS X556UR-XX477T

Comment: I would love to help you, but I have no experience with this system. You really need to put this into a new question, so that others who might know more can see it.

You could try to boot with `i8042.nopnp` as kernel boot parameter, but I doubt this helps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter.

Maybe also look at https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-keyboard-uunresponsive-after-resume-from-suspend/

Comment: I found this problem reported on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1902156. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by downloading the kernel 5.8.0-31-generic.